# Having a girlfriend

Tags: halacha, sexuality, shidduchim-dating

Is there anything wrong with a young man who is not looking to get married having a girlfriend? Assume that he would not touch her or have sex with her.

Comment: Is this question addressing men, specifically? Of what age? Is the "girlfriend" status a possible precursor to marriage?

Comment: Teenager or a young adult. Isaac Moses, what do you mean by status a possible precursor to marriage?

Comment: Is it possible that this relationship will result in the couple getting married? Is entertaining this possibility part of their intent? Please [edit] your question so that it's as clear as possible, and remove the sotah tag.

Comment: They are not getting married.

Comment: How is this different from dating before marriage? Or are you asking specifically about a relationship which would not have to lead to marriage?

Answer (score 11):

R' Moshe Feinstein in [Even HaEzer 4:60](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=921&pgnum=115) writes that it is absolutely prohibited, not just as a nice practice, but involves a Torah prohibition.

Among other points, one thing he writes is that in his understanding of the Rambam, speaking to a woman in an affectionate manner is included in the Torah prohibition of illicit relationships.

Comment: From your answer (and from the responsum) it seems he prohibits this even among couples of marriageable age. Is this your intent? Seems quite stringent. Am I missing something in the argument?

Comment: @DoubleAA That was his intent.  Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: He's allowed to take that position, just it doesn't seem very conducive for couples to get married. That means one can't tell their fiancee one likes her until after the Chuppah, right?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18031/discussion-on-answer-by-yez-having-a-girlfriend).